# Clean string using preg_replace, but admit latin characters

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, preg-replace

What I'm trying to do is clean up a string (html tags, extra white spaces, quotes...), but I want to admit Latin characters like punctuation and the `ñ` character. I tried this, but I can't figure out why is not working as expected:

#### Code

```
//Removing special characters
$str = preg_replace('/[^;\sa-zA-Z0-9áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+/', '', $str);
//Deleting extra white spaces
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
```

#### Example

```
in:       Película; Films; @Cine; Añoranza; <html></body>foo "bar    ";
out:      pelcula; Films; Cine; Aoranza;  foo bar
expected: Película; Films; Cine; Añoranza; foo bar
```

#### Question:

What is the problem with my code and how can I fix that? Because the Latin Characters part that is the only thing that is not working on the expression.

**Plus:** How can I merge both regex expression into one?

Comment: Tried `'/[^;\sa-zA-Z0-9áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+/u'`? Also, just tested, your regex will replace `<html></body>` into `htmlbody`, not what you claim you get as output.

Comment: mmm... I think the problem is Laravel framework or database

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/KNJ07).

Comment: is working on php console, but not in php file o.O

Comment: @Passerby: Thanks for the help, but the problem was due encoding issue

Comment: Then your file may not be in UTF-8. Try to follow @Esailija 's instruction and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `u` flag if you are using UTF-8.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^;\sa-zA-Z0-9áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+/u', '', $str);
```

Make sure your database connection is utf-8 and your php source file
physical encoding is utf-8 and it will all work. Your regex won't magically become a html parser though.

Comment: Database connection is UTF-8, but with the `u` flag I'm getting  
`preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 15`

Comment: @TomSarduy your php source file is not in UTF-8, what text editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text, how can I set this?

Comment: @TomSarduy   `"default_encoding": "UTF-8"` in `preferences.sublime-settings`

Comment: @TomSarduy well that setting only applies if *    // Encoding used when saving new files, and files opened with an undefined
    // encoding (e.g., plain ascii files). If a file is opened with a specific
    // encoding (either detected or given explicitly), this setting will be
    // ignored, and the file will be saved with the encoding it was opened
    // with.*

Comment: @TomSarduy explicitly use File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF-8

Comment: yeap, I never used the save with Encoding option. That work! Thanks for the free lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this (better looking) method:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}]+/u', '', $str);
```